# Switching multiple classes to WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an interface and multiple classes using that interface, also on the **server** there's a factory that creates a specific instance based on some parameters.

Now I'd have to expose those classes to WCF clients, I hoped that I'd be able to mark the interface as `OperationContract` and establish the communication, but it seems that on the server (I'm new to WCF) I have to create a service (or at least open a port) per class and I can't do that for an interface.

Is that the only way to do it or am I missing something?

Edit to clarify:
Say I have an interface with one method, let's call it `Execute(EnumedParam action)`.
I'd like to be able to call it from the client with

```
InterfaceType.Execute(Action.One);
```

and on the server to create an instance based on action and execute it's `Execute` method.

Also there might be many instances of the class and I'd like the client not to know anything about the classes, just the interface.

How can I do that over WCF?

(note: If my class model is totally wrong can you recommend a book or a blog where I can read more about this?)

*I can't paste code in comments for another edit*

Wouter de Kort gave great example of what am I doing. But how do I setup endpoints for that?
Looking at the example given here http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication - the author opens the port like this:

```
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
  typeof(StringReverser),
  new Uri[]{
    new Uri("http://localhost:8000"),
    new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")
  }))
{
```

Now that's where my problem is. The first parameter is a class (can't be an interface or abstract class). Do I have to do it for every class that extends the interface or can I somehow use the same host for multiple classes?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have the following service interface:

```
public interface IMyService 
{
    void Execute(EnumdParam action);
}
```

If you want to use this in WCF you will decorate it:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService 
{
   [OperationContract]
   void Execute(EnumdParam action);
}
```

On your client you have to create a Proxy to access the WCF Service.

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
public partial class MyServiceClient : ClientBase<IMyService>, IMyService
{
    public MyServiceClient ()
    {
    }

    public void Execute(EnumdParam action);
    {
        return base.Channel.Execute(action);
    }
}
```

As you can see, your client proxy implements `IMyService` so in your client code you only have to be aware of the `IMyService` interface. If you change your factory to return `MyServiceClient` instead of `MyService` nothing in your client code has to change (except for WCF configuration and making sure you dispose of the client).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've updated my post as an answer for you.

Comment: @user1164630 Setting up a host for your WCF services is another problem. In your example, a Console Application is used for hosting the WCF services. You can also choose to use IIS and put the configuration in your web.config file